# iOS Swift Disable PanGesture Based On Area Touched

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I disable the pan gesture if the user is touching a certain area? I have an area with some controls and if the player's finger is in that area, I don't want the view to pan.  My code for the gesture is:

```
@objc func panedView(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    mapButton?.isHidden = false
    self.camera?.constraints = [  ]
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    var pos = cameraNode.position

    pos.x -= translation.x
    pos.y += translation.y
    self.cameraNode.run(SKAction.move(to: pos, duration: 0.1))

}
```

Comment: make it optional and set it as nil  ?

Comment: Add a delegate to the gesture recognizer and implement `func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool`, return true only if the point is within desired area

Comment: gestureRecognizerShouldBegin did the trick.  Thanks!